# unformatting a formatted disk

Tags: hard-drive, nas, format

I have a ReadyNAS 104 with a two disks already installed. I have a third disk I want to add to it but the disk has been formatted for Windows. ReadyNAS has a process for re- (un-) formatting disks so that it can use them but it looks awkward. I would like to know if there is a simple way I can return the formatted disk to its original unformatted-straight-out-of-box state using an external usb enclosure connected to a Windows 10 PC?

Comment: I've never seen a hard drive that was unformatted (raw metal) straight out of the box.

Comment: I'm surprised a NAS doesn't have the ability to simply wipe the drive and prepare it for inclusion in the array built in.

Answer (score 0):

- In command prompt (<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>, `cmd`) run `diskpart`, then `list disk`, choose correct drive, then `select disk=X`, where `X` is the number of drive you would like to format (taken from `list disk`), then `clean` to delete partition table.
- Or, running disk eraser software like [DBAN](http://dban.org/) for a minute or so would destroy first blocks of disk resulting in being like out-of-the-box, but data would still be there